# Restrict url base Django Api with drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Hi I want to filter one of my Api models by one field. Building the queryset for the view I need to use the whole model using model.objects.all() and the model serializer. Once I set the filterset which the parameter I want to filter.

It filters correctly when I make the consult directly but the problem is when I access to the url for the filter, it by default shows me all the elements of this models and if I search for an element that not exist it also shows al the elements.

Those are my serializers.py to the full model and the filtered.

```
class EstacionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pistas = PistaSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    forfaits = ForfaitSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    #owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Estacion
        fields = ['nombre', 'ciudad', 'pais', 'descripcion',
                  'pistas', 'forfaits', 'km_esquiables', 'distancia_ciudad']


class EstacionBycFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Estacion
        fields = ['ciudad']
```

Those are my views.py where is use the full serializer and the filtered one.

```
class EstacionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Estacion.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EstacionSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,]


class EstacionByCiudad(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Estacion.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EstacionSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,]
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = EstacionPorCiudadFilterSet
```

Here are the urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'estaciones', views.EstacionViewSet, basename='estaciones')
router.register(r'pistas', views.PistaViewSet, basename='pistas')
router.register(r'forfaits', views.ForfaitViewSet, basename='forfaits')
router.register(r'busquedaciudad', views.EstacionByCiudad, basename='EstbyCiudad')
from rest_framework.authtoken import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token, name='ap-auth'),
]
```

For example if I go to the url: localhost:8000/busquedaciudad/?ciudad=somecity it returns me correctly the objects filtered but if I try localhost:8000/busquedaciudad/ it gives me all the objects of the model in the database as well as if I left ciudad parameter empty like: localhost:8000/busquedaciudad/?ciudad=

And what I want is how if the url is like: localhost:8000/busquedaciudad/ or localhost:8000/busquedaciudad/?ciudad= return 0 objects instead of all of them.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand you, with what I think I understand, you need to create a separate serializer that returns only that field and use it for the view

Comment: I don't understand your problem. paste your code here.

Comment: @Dev
Hi thanks for your replies I put the code and some examples of what I want to get. (I don't know if it's possible).